# Is it possible to hardcode shared library position in C program?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

Normally, programs (in Linux) use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to locate their shared libraries, but I want to use a custom-path, without permanently altering LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Basically, a bash-wrapper can achieve it easily:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my_lib_path/
/my_bin_path/myprogram $*
```

(Bash only alters LD_LIBRARY_PATH within this script and not permanently)

I was wondering if it is possible to do the same thing in pure C **in one single executable** without the ugly bash-hack. All paths and the exact names of the libraries are known at compile-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the `-rpath` option to `ld`, or, via your compiler `-Wl,-rpath`. It allows you to extend the search path. It is commonly used by executable that wish to load modules from some plugin directory. You may add as many directories as you want via this method.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime, the dynamic loader reads it once when the program is executed and never checks it again, you could use [dlopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) instead to load the shared library yourself:

```
dlopen("/path/to/shared/lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

This will only work if you load the library and use `dlsym()` at runtime to look-up symbols otherwise if you call functions in the library those references must be resolved at load time and AFAIK you have to use something like the bashscript.

Note: It's possible to change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in runtime if you re-execute the process, I've just tested this and it seems to work, but it's very hackish, it's possibly the only way to do it in `C`:

```
void *handle;
// first time check if path is not set
if (getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")==NULL) {
    //set it and re-execute the process
    setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/path/to/lib/", 1);
    execl(argv[0], argv[0], NULL);
}
// open the shared library the second time
handle = dlopen("test.so", RTLD_LAZY);
printf("%p\n", handle);
dlclose(handle);
```

Comment: This will only work if you `dlopen` the library, which is a relatively not portable thing to do. If you want to, use `libltdl`, which has a `lt_dladdsearchdir`.

Comment: @Robby75 you use `dlsym()` to look-up a symbol and call it, not sure if that's what you want, but that's the only way I could think of.

Comment: Beware: I believe that the dynamic loader reads LD_LIBRARY_PATH when it is invoked (before the program proper gets running) and ignores any subsequent changes, so `setenv()` inside the program may not work — or may not work everywhere.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes that's true, but what if the process is re-executed with `fork()` and `exec()` ?

Comment: I've used a technique where the process looks at its LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and if needed adjusts the path and `exec()`s itself again.  It was only experimental software; there are other problems for SUID root programs to deal with.  But it worked within its limits.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've just tried something similar :) it is very hackish but It looks like it's working, however I get a segfault if I print `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` second time after `execl()` any idea why ?

Comment: This approach has tons of problems. If you can use `dlopen` rather than linking directly to the library, then why would you set environment variables to do your work for you in hackish ways that might interfere with normal use of these variables, rather than just passing an absolute pathname to `dlopen`??

Comment: @R.. you wouldn't need to set the environment variable, I do pass an absolute path in the first part of the answer but I said you couldn't change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then I found out that you could so I added that. Also the question asks how to do that in `C` hence `dlopen`

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, when linking the program you can use `-Wl,-rpath` to add specific paths to the library search path for the application. However, if you just want to hard-code the path for a specific library, use that when linking rather than using the `-l` option. For instance, instead of `-lfoo`, just use `/opt/foo/lib/libfoo.so.1` on the linking command line.

Comment: `gcc -o myprogram /mypath/mylibrary.so mysource.c` does compile (so I'm sure that the shared object was found), but it still complains about the missing library when I try to run the program. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "linking command line".

Comment: Also potentially of interest is `chrtool` which allows the RPATH to be changed after linking - although it has lots of silly restrictions because it changes the path in place and can't make it any longer (or add one if none previously present).

Comment: @Robby75: Does `mylibrary.so` exist in `/mypath` when you run the binary? What does `readelf -a myprogram` show you regarding `mylibrary.so`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible at execution time : The library are loaded before executing the program...

But you can do it at compile time by passing the option `-rpath` to your linker